# Which form of set the adapter of the RecyclerView is better?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a doubt about setting the adapter of the RecyclerView, I have seen in some tutorials that they make the Adapter and then they make in the same class that they have the RecyclerView they set the information. But my teacher makes it in another way, he makes 4 class, the adapter, then this class to get all the information called MovieServices:

```
public class MoviesService
{
public static MoviesService moviesService;

public static MoviesService getInstance()
{
    if ( moviesService == null )
    {
        moviesService = new MoviesService();
    }

    return moviesService;
}

private List<Movie> movies;

private MoviesService()
{
    this.movies = new ArrayList<>();

    movies.add( new Movie("001", "El hombre que mató a Liberty Valance", 9.8) );
    movies.add( new Movie("002", "Río Rojo", 9.2) );
    movies.add( new Movie("003", "Río Bravo", 9.9) );
    movies.add( new Movie("004", "La diligencia", 9.1) );
    movies.add( new Movie("005", "Que verde era mi valle", 9.8) );
    movies.add( new Movie("006", "El hombre tranquilo", 9.3) );
    movies.add( new Movie("007", "Misión de audaces", 9) );
    movies.add( new Movie("008", "La taberna del irlandés", 8.6) );
    movies.add( new Movie("009", "El Padrino", 9.5) );
    movies.add( new Movie("010", "El Padrino II", 9.6) );
    movies.add( new Movie("011", "El Padrino III", 9.7) );
    movies.add( new Movie("012", "Los increibles", 9.2) );
    movies.add( new Movie("013", "Los increibles II", 8.9) );
    movies.add( new Movie("014", "Coco", 9.6) );
}

public List<Movie> getMovies()
{
    return movies;
}

public Movie getMovie(int position)
{
    return movies.get( position );
}


public void update(int moviePosition, Movie movie)
{
    movies.set(moviePosition, movie);
}
}
```

Then he called another class called

```
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel
{
private MoviesService moviesService;


public MainViewModel()
{
    moviesService = MoviesService.getInstance();
}

public List<Movie> getMovies()
{
    return moviesService.getMovies();
}

public Movie getMovie(int position)
{
    return moviesService.getMovie( position );
}
}
```

And finally the class which has the RecyclerView:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MovieAdapter.OnItemClickListener
{

private MainViewModel viewModel;
private RecyclerView rv;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private MovieAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
    this.rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);
    this.layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
    this.adapter = new MovieAdapter(this);
    this.adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    rv.setAdapter( adapter );
    rv.setLayoutManager( layoutManager );
    adapter.setMovies( viewModel.getMovies() );
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

    Movie movie = this.viewModel.getMovie(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, movie.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MovieActivity.class );
    intent.putExtra(MovieActivity.EXTRA_MOVIE_POSITION, position);
    startActivityForResult( intent, 88 );
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    switch ( requestCode )
    {
        case 88:  if ( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                  {
                      adapter.setMovies( viewModel.getMovies() );
                  }
                  break;
    }
}
}
```

But I'm not sure which way is more optimizated because I think he does a lot of things that I believe that are unncesary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the best approach is to create separate element following steps for a clean coding :

1- Create a separate custom object class

2- Create a separate ﻿`RecyclerView.Adapter` to populate data into the `RecyclerView`

3- Bind the Adapter to the `RecyclerView` in a separate Activity

Comment: So is better to set the Recycler's view data in a separate class instead of in the same Activity that you have the recyclerview¿?

Comment: Exactly , please consider my answer if it was helpful